# Bootstrap Table Hover with rowspan

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have this HTML Structure:

```
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td rowspan="2"></td>
    <td rowspan="2"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td align="center" rowspan="2"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Iam using class table-hover class when i hover on the first row which contains rowspan the second row that is with two columns does not reflect the background color.
I want whenever i hover either of the rows both should reflect the background color.

Comment: This is noy a valid html, question is not clear and what about the css you use?

Comment: You'll need to add more code: more complete HTML and the relevant CSS. Best would be a working example e.g. on jsfiddle. In any case, keep in mind the cells with `rowspan` are part of the first row. Anything happening with(in) the second row will not effect them.

Comment: Edit is pending, but I put together a working example for him: http://bootply.com/91978